# Copy and paste columns to another sheet based on a criteria

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

How do I copy and paste columns from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 which has the word "To" in its column headers?

Example, Column H Header = 12/2/2014 To 14/2/2014

I want to copy only these types of columns and paste it on another sheet.

P.S. I'm looking for a non-vba solution (if there is one) so any help would be much appreciated.

I've tried using this formula but nothing happens.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A$1,"*TO*"),Sheet1!A2,"")
```

P.S. I'm using Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Find formula that will return the number of "To" for that.

```
=IFERROR(FIND("To", A1, 1), "Did not found")
```

And in VBA you can use InStr that does almost the same operation.